# Forzar cambio de color de texto usando TweenMax

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo unos hipervínculos con el color por CSS con la propiedad `!important`, debido a que necesito cambiar su color por defecto, el cual les da otra hoja de estilos que no puedo/debo modificar.

```
.elementos {
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

Y tengo una animación con TweenMax que modifica el contenedor de `.elementos`. A esa animación necesito agregarle una propiedad para cambiar el color de los hipervínculos.

```
var contenedorAnimacion = tl
    .to(cabecera, 1, {backgroundColor: '#fff'})
    .to(caja, 1, {height: 0, autoAlpha: 0});
```

Necesito agregar el cambio de color. Ya intenté con:

```
var contenedorAnimacion = tl
    .to(cabecera, 1, {backgroundColor: '#fff'})
    .to(elementos, 1, {color: '#999'})
    .to(caja, 1, {height: 0, autoAlpha: 0});
```

Pero esto no me funciona. ¿Hay una manera de forzar el cambio o hacer que se ignore la propiedad `!important` del CSS?

Answer (score 1):

¿Has probado agregar el important en la animación por js?

```
var contenedorAnimacion = tl
    .to(cabecera, 1, {backgroundColor: '#fff !important'})
    .to(elementos, 1, {color: '#999 !important'})
    .to(caja, 1, {height: 0, autoAlpha: 0});
```

Aunque bueno, la verdad aunque lo anterior o no resuelva tu problema, no es el mejor consejo, lo mejor que te puedo recomendar es no usar **!important** precisamente por este caso. Ya que es una solución rápida, que funciona la mayoría de casos donde no se dispone de tiempo o de una mejor solución, cosa que en tu caso si la hay, de hecho para sobrescribir en css una hoja de estilos que en cascada abajo o ya asignada, lo mejor es usar la herencia, así:

Si quieres sobrescribir por ejemplo, **puedes usar un ancestro**:

```
.ancestro .elementos{
  background: #fff
}
```

O un **selector aún más especifico con más ancestros**:

```
.tatarancestro .bizcancestro .ancestro .elementos{
  background: #fff
}
```

O nada impide **usar etiquetas o ids**

```
html body #main .ancestro .elementos{
  background: #fff
}
```

Estos tendrán más "fuerza" para sobrescribir la hoja de estilos por defectos, a menos que use **!important** erroneamente, como tú lo hiciste.

De esta forma, por javascript los puedes modificar, ya que js usa estilos en línea para aplicar css o animaciones y estos por jerarquía tienen mayor "fuerza" para sobrescribir.

Lo otro es que controles donde poner tu hoja de estilos, es decir, si hay estilos del mismo tipo o selector, pero están por debajo, los últimos va a tener mayor "fuerza", "jerarquía" o "prioridad". Esto mismo se aplica para los links de archivos externos, por lo que si puedes controlar que va primero o despues, puedes optar por poner el tuyo despues, así:

```
<link href="estilos-por-defecto.css" />
<link href="mis-propios-estilos.css" />
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.